# How to design table between three important columns (products,designs,colorImages) in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I designed three tables

- Products
- Designs
- Colorimages

What is the best way to design extra tables to join these three table together:

- Each product have more than one design with more than colorimages of that design.

Example

```
productid    designid  colorimageid   picturename
1               1         1              img1
1               1         2              img2
1               2         1              img3
1               2         3              img4
1               3         1              img5
2               1         1              img6
2               1         2              img7
2               2         1
2               3         3
2               3         4
```

How to design it with high performance ?

Comment: This [link](http://www.blueclaw-db.com/tabledesignaccess/) will help you build your table structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a table (called `ProductDesignColor` perhaps) with fields

```
ProductID
DesignID
ColorImageID
```

plus its own ID column as an IDENTITY column called `ID`

For high speed, keep the integer data types in the smallest sensible size, perhaps 32 bit integers.

Build a Clustered index on the ID of the table.
Build a Composite index on the 3 main ID fields (P, D, C), this index will be used by all of your queries no doubt.
Also make single indexes on the 3 ID field (P, D, C) - So 3 indexes in total - only if you will be querying using a single ID value.

Also, performance is a factor of your complete design, so your `Product` table should have ProductID as a Primary Key (Index).  Same with the other tables...  Indexes are the key to performance, but they have to be considered and used carefully.  Or if you have the RAM - the more indexes the better (unless you are doing lots of inserts / updates).
So a good,neat table design also leads to well planned, minimal, powerful indexes that can fit neatly in the available RAM.

Comment: what is the performance of new table (ProductDesignColor) if i set pid ,Did,Cid as primarykey ?

Comment: That could be fine too.  It depends how you will update and read the data really, and the other links to 'Product Range' for example.  Sometimes a Primary Key on a single ID field is better, sometimes not.  It really depends on many factors...So the best answer is to experiment with your real data and hardware

Comment: 'Performance' can mean many things, so it might help if you are more specific... Performance reading lots of data from the database?  Querying data?  Many many Users? Adding data? Tracking changes? Audit logs?  There are alot of factors...

Comment: For performance, you dont want your Primary Key (Clustered index) to be rebuilt or to become fragmented when you Insert or Update ... So thats why an IDENTITY column is often best as the Primary Key.  Or rebuild your indexes when the load is low on the Servers

Comment: i am developing e commerce website with all feature of any e commerce , most work on it, is searching ,quering data,adding data and many users (admins) can add or update or delete . and when any user or customer want to search ,will search by color or design of products . until now didnot know best away to design table with only id as primary key or 3 fields (p,d,c) as primary key .

Comment: It still depends on how often you insert or update...Is that automatic?  Do your products grow (more colors etc) very fast?  Etc... Your answer makes sense, but is still vague.  I think Primary key is best on a single field - to preserve the index integrity - it is just a better design with good 'overall' performance, and often high performance for common scenarios

Comment: Once you have more than a few million rows, everything takes on some new dynamics, and different performance aspects must be looked at... So there is no perfect answer until you test it

Comment: The database design fully depends on the whole solution, not on 3 tables. You need to know the counts, the read/write ratio, required level of product, design and image description. Sometimes 1 table holding all information can be more effective than academically perfect schema...